# Can't login to azure portal

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-authentication

I installed fresh copy of Windows 10 on my PC today. I am facing issue while login to portal.azure.com site. Every time I login, it keeps redirecting to following site and finally stops on the login page with error:

> We couldn’t sign you in. Please try again.

Below are the links where it keeps redirecting in the loop:

1. [https://login.microsoftonline.com/7bbfa0c2-{someId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.azure.com%2Fsignin%2Findex%2F&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F%2Fuser_impersonation%20openid%20email%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DX4KUAReK{sometext}&response_mode=form_post&nonce=6382547281{sometext}&client_id=c44b4083-{sometext}&site_id=504560&client-request-id=8c473a6{sometext}&x-client-SKU=ID_NET472&x-client-ver=6.30.1.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/7bbfa0c2-%7BsomeId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.azure.com%2Fsignin%2Findex%2F&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F%2Fuser_impersonation%20openid%20email%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DX4KUAReK%7Bsometext%7D&response_mode=form_post&nonce=6382547281%7Bsometext%7D&client_id=c44b4083-%7Bsometext%7D&site_id=504560&client-request-id=8c473a6%7Bsometext%7D&x-client-SKU=ID_NET472&x-client-ver=6.30.1.0)
2. [https://portal.azure.com/signin/index/7bbfa0c2-{someId}](https://portal.azure.com/signin/index/7bbfa0c2-%7BsomeId%7D)

The same login works fine on another machine and on my mobile.

I tried different browsers like Edge, Chrome, Chrome Beta, Firefox and incognito windows. All other logins like outlook.com using same account works but not the azure portal. I also tried clearing cache but its not working.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Clear cookies, try in incognito mode, try a different browser, log out of all your Hotmail/Outlook/MS accounts and close the browser and try again.

Comment: Yes tried these but its not working. Also updated the question with steps taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to fix the issue. My machine's Date & Time was out of sync. Though clock was showing India Time its time zone was set to US and Canada.

When I changed the Time Zone to Indian Time and click Sync now under Synchronize your clock, the issue of logging to azure portal got fixed.

Reason I checked this setting was Teams app was showing timing in US time zone though my Office 365 region is set to India. So while fixing Teams timing issue, portal.azure.com related issue is also fixed.